# Directory not copied - Docker

Tags: python, docker, cython

Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM python:alpine3.14 AS cython-compile
WORKDIR /tmp/cython
COPY /data/python .
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
    pip3 install --no-cache-dir cython && \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-dependencies gcc musl-dev && \
    python3 setup.py build

FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /data
COPY --from=cython-compile /tmp/cython .
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    testtest:
        container_name: ztz-test
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "7776:7776"
        volumes:
            - .:/data
```

When I run the command `docker-compose build` there is no error at all but the file compiled by cython is not copied. I have confirmed that the file is in **/tmp/cython** by commenting this line:

```
FROM alpine:latest
WORKDIR /data
COPY --from=cython-compile /tmp/cython .
```

Comment: The `volumes:` in your Dockerfile are replacing everything in the final image's `/data` directory with arbitrary content from the host.  You should delete that block to use the built content from the image.

Comment: So I have to delete `volumes: .:/data`? is there no other way?